# Запрос в запросе SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Подскажите как составить запрос в SQL. Надо сначала найти все записи с значением 1 в поле ID_USERS затем из этих записей выбрать одну у которой самая большая дата.

Comment: @АлексейШиманскийтак выводит все записи с последней датой

Comment: @АлексейШиманскийтак так выводит запись с id 5 а не с 1.

Comment: странно .... `SELECT * FROM table WHERE ID_USERS  = 1 AND date = (SELECT MAX(date) FROM table WHERE ID_USERS = 1) LIMIT 1` ?

Comment: @АлексейШиманскийтак ваш вариант заработал спасибо) вот тоже рабочий вроде как вариант
 
`SELECT * From users_sum WHERE id_users = 3 ORDER BY data DESC LIMIT 1`

Comment: Воот и сами справились) я про то, что не надо запрос в запросе в начале написал...только почему-то решил сделать как вы захотели)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вариант 1

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE ID_USERS = 1 AND date = (SELECT MAX(date) FROM table WHERE ID_USERS = 1) LIMIT 1
```

Вариант 2

```
SELECT * From users_sum WHERE id_users = 3 ORDER BY data DESC LIMIT 1
```